# Как добавить запись в реестр?

Tags: python, реестр

такая проблема - вот так работает

```
import _winreg
key = _winreg.OpenKey(_winreg.HKEY_CURRENT_USER,"SOFTWARE\\Microsoft\\Windows\\CurrentVersion\\Run",0, _winreg.KEY_ALL_ACCESS)
_winreg.SetValueEx(key, "Strike", 0, _winreg.REG_SZ,"D:\Games\sozdanie puti.py")
key.Close()
```

если я меняю `HKEY_CURRENT_USER` на `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE` выдает такую ошибку

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\СК\Desktop\reestr.py", line 3, in <module>
key = _winreg.OpenKey(_winreg.HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE,"SOFTWARE\\Microsoft\\Windows\\CurrentVersion\\Run",0, _winreg.KEY_ALL_ACCESS)
WindowsError: [Error 5]
```

ошибка 5 это вроде как ошибка прав доступа...подскажите как исправить ошибку ..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Выполнить скрипт от имени администратора. От имени простого юзера вы имеете доступ на чтение и запись в ветку реестра `HKEY_CURRENT_USER`, а ветку `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE` вы можете только читать.

Comment: это его надо в формат exe переводить или есть другой способ ?

Comment: Есть способ: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19672352/how-to-run-python-script-with-elevated-privilege-on-windows