# Есть в Windows команда аналогичная команде "sudo" в GNU/Linux?

Tags: windows

Как запускать скрипты от root`a в windows?

Comment: cmd запустить от имени администратора.

Comment: Я запускаю скрипт на python`e через cmd от администратора для записи программу в автозагрузку через реестр,  он пишет мне  "Отказано в доступе"

Comment: Вчера был подобный вопрос уже. Как раз о питоне и ветке HKEY_CURRENT_USER. http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/482768/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%8C-%D0%B2-%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80   может поможет чем то )

Answer (score 15, accepted):

```
runas /user:username "command.exe /parameters"
```

`runas /user:mymachine\administrator cmd.exe` - запустить интерпретатор команд cmd.exe от имени пользователя "administrator" компьютера "mymachine". При выполнении команды, будет запрошен пароль пользователя, от имени которого должна выполняться задача.

`runas /noprofile /env /user:mydomain\admin " mmc %windir%\system32\diskmgmt.msc "` - запустить консоль mmc с оснасткой "Управление дисками" от имени пользователя "admin" в домене "mydomain". Профиль пользователя не загружается, и используются текущие переменные среды. Загрузка профиля пользователя необходима только тогда, когда будет выполняться задача, которой требуются какие-либо данные из него. Если задан параметр `/env` то переменные окружения наследуются из среды текущего пользователя.

`runas /savecred /user:admin@mydomain regedit.exe` - запустить редактор реестра "regedit.exe" от имени пользователя "admin" домена "mydomain" с запоминанием введенного пароля. При наличии параметра `/savecred`, введенный пароль запоминается в реестре в зашифрованном виде и в дальнейшем запрашиваться не будет .

`runas /showtrustlevel` - отобразить уровни доверия, существующие в системе. В ответ будет отображаться перечень в виде:

> В системе доступны следующие уровни доверия:
>   0x20000 (Обычный пользователь)

Кроме значения `trustlevel` равного `0x20000` можно пользоваться значениями `0x10000`, соответствующему минимальному набору привилегий и `0x40000`, стандартному для данного пользователя набору. Для просмотра отличий разных уровней доверия можно воспользоваться командой `Whoami`, выполняя ее в сеансе командного процессора, запускаемого с каждым из уровней `trustlevel`

`runas /trustlevel:0x20000 cmd.exe` - запустить командный процессор cmd.exe с использованием уровня доверия, полученного в предыдущем примере.

`runas /trustlevel:0x40000 cmd.exe` - запустить командный процессор cmd.exe с использованием стандартного уровня доверия.

Примечание: в сеансе командной строки, запущенной с использованием параметра `/trustlevel`, список привилегий соответствующий каждому уровню доверия можно получить с использованием команды `whoami /priv`, а полные сведения об учетной записи - `whoami /ALL`

Примечание: параметр `/profile` несовместим с параметром `/netonly.

Примечание: параметр `/savecred` несовместим с параметром `/smartcard`.

Вот вариант с передачей пароля:

```
echo пароль | runas /netonly /user:workgroup\user "command.exe"
```

Answer (score 1):

Команды аналогичной "sudo" нет.

Для Winows Vista-10:

Можно запустить cmd от имени администратора или выбрать это в свойствах ярлыка.

Если cmd запущена с правами администратора, в заголовке окна появляется слово "Администратор"; команда `whoami /groups` показывает в последней строке SID `S-1-16-12288` вместо `S-1-16-8192`; команды `net session` или `dir C:\Windows\Temp` работают (имеют доступ).
В этом случае cmd и скрипт имеют максимальные права администратора, но не имют неограниченного доступа. В свойствах папки / безопасность и также для ключей реестра можно запретить доступ также для администратора. Администратор имеет возможность изменить эти настройки, но до того они действуют. Но в редких случаях прав администратора действительно не хватает, это самозащита Windows.

Большинство программ также получают права администратора, если их запустить в cmd от администратора. Исключение - Windows Explorer имеет всегда ограниченные права. Проверить это можно в Диспетчере Задач / Подробности / скрытый столбец "С более высоким уровнем разрешений"
или в ProcessExplorer / скрытый столбец "Process Image/Integrity Level"

`runas`подходит только для Windows XP/2003, но не меняет ничего в Windows Vista - 10 из-за UAC (User Account Control).

Смотрите также https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1894967/how-to-request-administrator-access-inside-a-batch-file

Answer (score 0):

Есть sudo для windows https://chocolatey.org/packages/Sudo. А еще менеджер пакетов chocolatey)

Answer (score 0):

Можно создать "sudo.cmd" скрипт:

```
@ECHO off

set command=%~$PATH:1
set tmpfile="%temp%\tmp-sudo-%~nx1.vbs"
set params=

:loop
shift
if [%1]==[] goto afterloop
if [%1]==[%~1] (set params=%params% %1) else (set params=%params% "%1")
goto loop

:afterloop
set params=%params:~1%
echo Set objShell = CreateObject("Shell.Application")> %tmpfile%
echo objShell.ShellExecute "%command%", "%params%", "", "runas">> %tmpfile%
cscript //D //Nologo //T:30 %tmpfile%

del %tmpfile%
```

Использование: sudo command

sudo cmd.exe

sudo cmd.exe /K net session

sudo calc.exe

[скриншот](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TQLsp.png)