# Как отредактировать реестр через python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, windows, реестр

Допустим надо в ветке *HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\DataCollection* изменить двоичные данные *AllowTelemetry* на *00000000*

Знаю что можно создать файл **.reg** и прописать :
`[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\DataCollection]`

`"AllowTelemetry"=dword:00000000`

Но нужно сделать это через python

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/482768/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%8C-%D0%B2-%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80

Comment: @Namerek там описывается ошибка - не понятно какие параметры что обозначают, есть какие нибудь документации\гайды ?

Comment: А доки по либе почитать. Не?

Comment: Та я погуглил ничего не нашел \0_0/

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/library/winreg.html

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19672352/how-to-run-python-script-with-elevated-privilege-on-windows

Comment: угу спасибо....

Comment: Невачта.... )))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Отредактировать реестр можно с помощью библиотеки **winreg**
*Документалка*: https://docs.python.org/3/library/winreg.html
*Код*:

```
import winreg  
winreg.SetValue(key, sub_key, type, value)
```